# Error message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: symbolData

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, geocortex, geocortex-essentials

I am trying to reference a web map in Geocortex Essentials but it will not let me and gives the following error message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: symbolData.

I isolated the layers in my web map and see that there are two layers causing this issue. The layers that don't work and the ones that do show no schema differences (they have different features). But no feature has a null value and I tried changing the symbology of the problematic layers to match the ones that work. Still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I found when I got that error:

- I was adding a polygon feature service to an empty Geocortex site in Essentials Manager.
- A point and line feature service from the same published MXD/mapservice could both be added without issue
- The polygon layer in the source MXD had about 20 different 'create feature templates', 4 of which had funky symbology including dashed outlines and/or hashing.
- I simplified all symbols to plain outline and fill types, and (importantly) regenerated the 'create feature templates' for the polygon layer.
- After republishing the MXD the layer became addable to Gx.

Comment: Thanks, I also found that simplifying my complex symbology resolved the issue. AGOL can also only handle certain symbology when creating a hosted feature service. So it is better as a simple line. It's just a shame that I have to dumb it down in the first place because of Esri...